# Multiple Domains - User access

Tags: sharepoint-online, external-users

We have two domains abc.com and abc.net.  All the accounts associated with abc.com on O365.  However, abc.net accounts are on google and we cannot change this for various reasons. Now we want to give access to abc.net users access to intranet developed on abc.com.

1) Are any ways to give access to abc.net users without enable external sharing?

2) If external sharing is the only way what would be best way to enable 'everyone' on abc.net rather than adding individuals.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

External sharing would be a requirement, and right now, must be added individually. In addition, external sharing for non-OD4B sources (see https://blogs.office.com/2016/04/12/onedrive-for-business-recognized-as-an-efss-leader-and-continues-momentum-with-spring-updates/) still requires a Microsoft Account or Office 365 organizational identity.